# Pandas filter 2 dataframes for overlaps

Tags: pandas

I have to pandas dataframes.
A looks like this:

```
from         to    arrive service
trainstation mall  12:30  T0A34
mall         BKA   13:00  T0A36
BKA          mill  12:34  T0A37
police       bar   12:31  T0A38
post office  church15:30  T0A3
trainstation mall  11:30  T0A34
...
```

B like this:

```
service date
T0A3     13-12-2019
T0A31    13-12-2019
T0A34    13-12-2019
T0A36    13-12-2019
T0A38    13-12-2019
T0A39    13-12-2019
T0A3     13-12-2019
...
```

The data shows which ride service is available at which dates.
I have already written code that filters out the rides in A which are a avilable at a given date by B.
The problem is, there are a lot of entries in both A and B making the code very slow.
So now I would like to filter out the entries in B that do not have an entry in A.
(for this example this line :T0A39    13-12-2019)
How can I do that without merging the two lists?

Comment: `b = b.loc[b['service'].isin(A['service'].unique())]`

Comment: thanks, that should work